# yarn android causing activity not found however gradlew run works

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native application that I am trying to run via yarn. Here are the two scripts I am trying to run.

The First script successfully installs the app and i have to manually open it from emulator. However the second script should install and launch the app with metro builder however it gives error

```
    "and": "cd android && ./gradlew installDevDebug",
    "android": "react-native run-android --mode=DevDebug",
```

My build.gradle has these details

```
flavorDimensions ("environment")
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        sandbox {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".sandbox"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }
```

Error i get is

```
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.app/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Why is yarn android not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your appIdSuffix is wrong. Try to change your script as follow

```
"android": "react-native run-android --mode=DevDebug --appIdSuffix=dev"
```